# Access SQL - How to get a second column from table field built on row source value list type?

Tags: sql, ms-access, self-join

I've created a simple table - table1.

- thre is only one talbe (table1)
- the table1 has two fields: [table1].[id] and [table1].[method]
- the RowSourceType of [table1].[method] is - 'Value list'
- the Row Source of [table1].[method] is  is ' 1;"A";35;"B";2;"C";3;"D" ' (so two columns).

> RowSourceType  - Value list 
> Row Source -  1;"A";35;"B";2;"C";3;"D"

**I've populated table1 with rows:**

| id | method |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

**I'm loking for a query to receive result:**

| [table1].[id] | [table1].[ method] |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A |

(I'd like to avoid to add lookup table)

Thank You in advance.
rgds

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Switch`:

```sql
Select 
    id, 
    Switch([method]=1,"A",[method]=35,"B",[method]=2,"C",[method]=3,"D") As MethodCode
From
    table1
```

Comment: Thank You for your help. 
Ok It works. Only small change neede  ([method]="1"), but Gustav's soution cause small problem when a new row will be add to [table1].[metod]. In this case it will be necessary to find and change sql as well.
Maybe there is a smother way ?

Comment: Perhaps. You could create a _lookup table_ with a record for each value/code pair. Then _join_ that in your query.

Comment: yep, lookup table is the easier way but it will cause extra inner join in the query. I'm thinking if I'll find a way to get into [table1].[metod].column2 I'll don't need it. I'm trying with self-join but without success.

Comment: You could create a function that retrieves the valuelist from the combox, takes the `method` as parameter, finds the method code, and returns this. Then use this function in your query. But a join to a lookup table will be faster, and you could replace the valuelist of the combobox with the same table.

Comment: at the moment it looks like it's not a good idea to create a lookup value list field when it contains more than one column. Thanks Gustav for you interest !

Comment: That, of course, depends. Yet a method is to use an Access special, a _Callback_ function, as source for the combobox. Study my articles: [Callback functions in Microsoft Access VBA](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/35774/Callback-functions-in-Microsoft-Access-VBA-Part-1.html?preview=KkyJtTCvMUs%3D).

Answer (score 1):

As @Gustav suggested and perhaps you didn't understand, first step is to create a lookup table, second step is to use that as your RowSource, third step is to build your query

Benefits of this approach is that you don't need to change your Rowsource every time you make a change to the Lookup List

**1. Create Lookup Table to match your rowsource**

| LookupID | LookupValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 35 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

**2-a. Change Rowsource of your input field**

In Properties | Data
Set Rowsource to

> SELECT LookupID, LookupValue FROM LookupTable

Set RowsourceType to

> Table/Query

[image: Rowsource]

**2-b Still in Properties | Format, set up columns and Hide the ID field**

```
ColumnCount =2
ColumnWidths = 0;3cm
```

[image: Column Setup]

**3. Build your final query**

```
SELECT Table1.ID, LookupTable.LookupValue
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN LookupTable ON Table1.metod = LookupTable.LookupID;
```

**Results of Query**

| ID | LookupValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A |

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: Tables still need to be in text. There's barely enough in the answer for it to not qualify as link-only, but as a general rule, if it's text, you shouldn't only have pictures of it. Images aren't searchable, they aren't copyable, and they are not accessible. Image-only answers remain subject to deletion.

Comment: Adjusted answer with tables - handy format. Didn't know how to use that. I think it's a little dramatic to say it was a link-only answer.